# Avoiding gridlines in phpexcel

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, phpexcel

I am trying to generate an dynamic excel file using **phpexcel**.
Is it possible to avoid grid lines in the output?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this,

```
$objPhpExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridlines(false);
```

this work for me...

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$objPhpExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridlines(False);
```

Comment: it's not an error, in excel there is an option as "Toggle Grid Lines For Current Sheet". is it possible to enable that from phpexcel

Comment: Ok, atm you must use the [setPrintGridlines](http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Worksheet/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#methodsetPrintGridlines) function or the [setShowGridlines](http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Worksheet/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#methodsetShowGridlines) function.